# CLI command to capture region with delay?

Tags: command-line, kde, screenshot

Of all screen-shot tools that I have seen in Linux, the KDE one (`ksnampshot`) looks the most powerful.

`ksnapshot --region` is a command that I can associate with a shortcut to capture a selected region without opening the Ksnapshot GUI.

The GUI, on the other hand, has a supplementary option of setting a delay for capturing the region:

[image]

Can that be done with a command too? I don't see a delay argument mentioned in `ksnapshot --help-all`.

Can `ksnapshot` or other tool do that, namely allowing a **CLI  command to capture rectangular region with delay**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, the most simple probably `sleep(1)`:

```
sleep 1m && ksnapshot --region ...
```

Using `&&` instead of `;` has the added benefit of the possibility to cancel the command with `CTRL C`.

Comment: a shortcut for `sleep 5s && ksnapshot --region` was what I  was looking for. the 3 points (ellipsis) not needed

Answer (score 0):

Check out `man at`.  I believe something like:

```
at -f <(printf %s 'ksnapshot --region ...') 'now + 1 minutes'
```

will do what you want.

This uses bash process substitution so the whole thing can fit on one line.  If you don't mind adding the snapshot command to a file before running the command, then it will look like:

```
at -f file_that_contains_the_command 'now + 5 minutes'
```